# Por que o meta é tão monótono?

Tags: debate

O meta raramente tem perguntas novas, são apenas edições/resposta em posts antigos(não estou dizendo que não são importantes, gosto muito de alguns).

- Não seria bom promovermos mais o meta, tentar conversar com os *staffs* para deixar um banner ou algo parecido, assim creio que consiguiriamos mais discussões úteis sobre o site e outros bugs, pelo que vejo antigamente o meta era mais ativo.

Comment: Ainda bem né, o ideal seria ter zero perguntas, o que significa que ninguém tem dúvidas, não há problemas, ainda que a parte monótona é que também não teria novidades para anunciar. Promover o meta para acontecer o que? Eu acho inclusive muita gente já cansou de discutir o site, principalmente porque quase tudo não vai a lugar algum. Quase tudo de interessante já foi discutido, Quase todas discussões novas acabam não sendo úteis, mesmo que bem intencionadas. O meta exige muito comprometimento com o site. Notou que alguns candidatos nunca usaram o meta, nem mesmo durante a eleição?

Comment: Se houvesse uma quantidade razoável de usuários querendo discutir o site, o meta seria menos monótono. Mesmo se fosse para repetir discussões que já foram feitas, mas dessa vez com outro grupo de usuários, eu acharia positivo. Não acho que o ideal é ter zero perguntas. Um meta ativo seria consequência de uma comunidade ativa, coisa que tem feito muita falta ao site. Quanto ao staff, parece ser intencional da parte deles se manterem meio afastados. Não sei se entendo muito bem os motivos.

Comment: Veja a [lista de privilégios](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges), quando o usuário alcança 5 pontos de reputação ganha o privilégio de [participar no META](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/participate-in-meta). Possivelmente há uma falta de disposição da comunidade em usufruir do privilégio, mas debates acontecem. O site está ai para ser utilizado, quem se interessar veja  [O que é o "META"? Como ele funciona?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta) e não deixe de conferir a [lista de tags](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/tags).

Comment: E como aqui não dá reputação, só participa quem realmente tem interesse no site; isso corrobora com o fato de ser *mais parado*.