# Teremos outro Moderators Award no futuro?

Tags: debate

[Esta pergunta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7524/o-que-voc%c3%aa-quer-aprender-em-2019-moderators-award-2019) feita aqui no META me chamou (de uma maneira positiva) bastante atenção. Como eu sei que o META é para tratar de assuntos menos técnicos, sobre a plataforma e assuntos descontraídos ou sérios (me corrijam se estiver errado), eu gostei e fiquei curioso com a iniciativa *Moderators Award*. Me paraceu uma maneira de fazer a comunidade interagir e, ao meu entender, foi uma iniciativa dos moderadores, correto? O que resultou em respostas criativas e descontraídas...

Como eu comecei a ser mais ativo na comunidade a partir do segundo semestre de 2020, logo essa premiação passou despercebida por mim, mas eu gostaria de saber:

- Teremos essa iniciativa de Moderatos Awards novamente?
- Essa iniciativa veio para incentivar mais os usuários a [participar e interagir no META](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8459/por-que-o-meta-%c3%a9-t%c3%a3o-mon%c3%b3tono)? Ou foi um evento isolado apenas para descontrair?
- Se eu quiser propôr um Moderator Award 2021, mesmo não sendo um moderador, posso tomar esta iniciativa?
- Iniciativas como essa são bem vindas na comunidade?

Essa premiação gerou boas interações e discussões sobre os usuários e suas preferências, planos, tecnologias, etc..., e gostaria de saber mais para não ficar de fora da próxima... se tiver!. :)

Comment: Se não me engano isso foi iniciativa do utluiz (que hoje é mod aposentado). Foi uma boa idéia mesmo. O [Nicholas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/17539/nicolas-chabanovsky) anda procriando por maneiras de engajar a comunidade. Talvez valha a pena falar com ele para ver se não rola uma iniciativa oficial da Stack Exchange; isso seria algo bem bacana. Se não rolar algo oficial e os CMs quiserem promover algo assim de novo eu me voluntário para passar o chapéu e levantar uma grana para o prêmio.

Comment: Eu achei que teve ano passado, mas pelo visto ninguém mencionou. Na minha opnião, poderiamos realizar algo através de iniciativas dos usuários mais ativos, não necessariamente moderadores e sim qualquer um que visite e participe ativamente do SOpt. Neste de 2019, percebi que muitos participaram, sejam aqueles com alta ou baixa pontuação, ou seja, foi um evento que todos poderam participar e, de certa forma, fez com que muitos usuários do SOpt participacem da comunidade aqui no META. Se essa iniciativa for aprovada, eu estou disposto a contribuir (financeiramente se necessario) nesse eventos.

Comment: Um prêmio interessante é algum item personalizado do SOpt